# Select Random Radio Button on Selenium PHP Web Driver

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium PHP Web Driver. I'm very new to this Selenium world.

I have 2 radio option

[image]

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div>Gender</div>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked="checked"> Male
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female
    </label>
</div>
```

---

**Selecting the Locator**

```
$gender = $webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::name,"gender");
if ($gender) {
    $gender->click("xpath=(//input[@name='gender'])[2]");
}
```

---

I can't seem to make it click on my second option.

Did I missed anything ?

---

Here is my whole file

**cp.php**

```
<?php

require_once "phpwebdriver/WebDriver.php";

$length = 2;
$str = '';
for ($x = 0; $x <= 5; $x++) {
    $randomString = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);
    $str = $str.$randomString.':';
}
$mac = strtoupper(substr($str, 0, -1));


$user = shell_exec('curl https://randomuser.me/api/');
$user = json_decode($user,true);
$user = $user['results'][0]['user'];

$rand_first = ucfirst($user['name']['first']);
$rand_last = ucfirst($user['name']['last']);
$rand_email = $user['email'];


$webdriver = new WebDriver("localhost", "4444");
$webdriver->connect("firefox");
$webdriver->get("http://localhost:8888/captive-portal?client_mac=".$mac.'&ap=00:0D:67:66:F2:F6&original_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.apple.com');


$first_name = $webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::name, "firstname");
if ($first_name) {
    $first_name->sendKeys(array($rand_first));
}

$last_name = $webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::name, "lastname");
if ($last_name) {
    $last_name->sendKeys(array($rand_last));
}

$email = $webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::name, "email");
if ($email) {
    $email->sendKeys(array($rand_email));
}

//Issues
$age = $webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::name,"age");
if ($age) {
    $age->click("xpath=(//input[@name='age'])[2]");
}

//Issues
$gender = $webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::name,"gender");
if ($gender) {
    $gender->click("xpath=(//input[@name='gender'])[2]");
}


$submit = $webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::id, "btn-cp-submit");
if ($submit) {
    $submit->submit();
}

$webdriver->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not a PHP coder so I hope that this is all correct.  I am not 100% clear on which PHP Selenium wrapper you are using, that would definitely help.  I am going to write some of these examples using https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver .

When you do:

```
$gender = $webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::name,"gender");
if ($gender) {
    $gender->click("xpath=(//input[@name='gender'])[2]");
}
```

You are only ever giving it the first instance of the radio button.  And then you are trying to pass a click event which you can't pass variables to.  Click is a function, but doesn't have any arguments.

If you want to have some random generated button you could do something like this:

```
$gender = $webdriver->findElementsBy(LocatorStrategy::name,"gender");
if (rand() % 2 == 0) {
    $gender[0]->click();
}else{
    $gender[1]->click();
}
```

You'll notice one tiny difference, I am using FindElement**s**By() with a plural **Elements** which says grab all of these on the page and store them in an array.

I am not 100% sure how the arrays work with the php version, but something like that should work for you.